# Android - Are these values normal for an app?

Tags: android, performance, android-profiler

I need to say i'm very new to android. Lately in my recycler view when i load over 100 items (mostly pictures) my app first lags then closes itself without error message. These are profiler values. What i want to know is are these values normal? if not what is normal value. I guess i need to mention that this is sharing app like facebook.

[image: Android Profiler 1]

[image: Android Profiler 2]

[image: Android Profiler 3]

My adapter code:

```
if(list.get(position).getPost().getTogroup()!=null){
            holder.groupname.setText(list.get(position).getPost().getTogroup());
            holder.profilephoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.namebelow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.groupname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.usernamebelow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(list.get(position).getPost().getGroupppurl()).into(holder.profilephoto);
            holder.namebelow.setText(list.get(position).getUser().getNamesurname());
            holder.usernamebelow.setText("(@"+list.get(position).getUser().getUsername()+")");
            if(list.get(position).getPost().getType().equals("text")){
                if(!list.get(position).getPost().getDescription().equals("")){
                    holder.descrition.setText(list.get(position).getPost().getDescription());
                    holder.descrition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
            if(list.get(position).getPost().getType().equals("link")){
                holder.linkpreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String url=list.get(position).getPost().getUrl();
                String linkimageurl=list.get(position).getPost().getLinkimageurl();
                if(holder.itemView.getContext()!=null){
                    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(linkimageurl).into(holder.linkimage);

                }
                String linktitle=list.get(position).getPost().getLinktitle();
                holder.linktitle.setText(linktitle);
                String linkdesc = list.get(position).getPost().getLinkdesc();
                holder.linkdesc.setText(linkdesc);
                holder.linkurl.setText(url);

                String description = list.get(position).getPost().getDescription();
                if(!description.equals("")){
                    holder.descrition.setText(description);
                    holder.descrition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            if(list.get(position).getPost().getType().equals("image")){



                float iratio = list.get(position).getPost().getImageratio();
                holder.imagelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.postimage.setRatio(iratio);
                String url=list.get(position).getPost().getUrl();

                if(holder.itemView.getContext()!=null){
                    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(url).addListener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            holder.imageloadingbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).into(holder.postimage);
                }

                String description = list.get(position).getPost().getDescription();;
                if(!description.equals("")){
                    holder.descrition.setText(description);
                    holder.descrition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            if(list.get(position).getPost().getType().equals("video")){
                holder.videoplayerjz.widthRatio=1;
                holder.videoplayerjz.heightRatio=1;
                holder.videoplayerjz.fullscreenButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.videoplayerjz.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String url=list.get(position).getPost().getThumburl();

                holder.videoplayerjz.setUp(
                        list.get(position).getPost().getUrl(),
                        "", Jzvd.SCREEN_WINDOW_LIST);
                if(holder.itemView.getContext()!=null){
                    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(url).into(holder.videoplayerjz.thumbImageView);

                }

                String description = list.get(position).getPost().getDescription();
                if(!description.equals("")){
                    holder.descrition.setText(description);
                    holder.descrition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

        }
        if(list.get(position).getPost().getTogroup()==null){
            holder.profilephoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.namecenter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.usernamecenter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(list.get(position).getUser().getProfilephotourl()).into(holder.profilephoto);
            holder.namecenter.setText(list.get(position).getUser().getNamesurname());
            holder.usernamecenter.setText("(@"+list.get(position).getUser().getUsername()+")");
            if(list.get(position).getPost().getType().equals("text")){
                if(!list.get(position).getPost().getDescription().equals("")){
                    holder.descrition.setText(list.get(position).getPost().getDescription());
                    holder.descrition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
            if(list.get(position).getPost().getType().equals("link")){
                holder.linkpreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String url=list.get(position).getPost().getUrl();
                String linkimageurl=list.get(position).getPost().getLinkimageurl();
                if(holder.itemView.getContext()!=null){
                    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(linkimageurl).into(holder.linkimage);

                }
                String linktitle=list.get(position).getPost().getLinktitle();
                holder.linktitle.setText(linktitle);
                String linkdesc = list.get(position).getPost().getLinkdesc();
                holder.linkdesc.setText(linkdesc);
                holder.linkurl.setText(url);

                String description = list.get(position).getPost().getDescription();
                if(!description.equals("")){
                    holder.descrition.setText(description);
                    holder.descrition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            if(list.get(position).getPost().getType().equals("image")){



                float iratio = list.get(position).getPost().getImageratio();
                holder.imagelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.postimage.setRatio(iratio);
                String url=list.get(position).getPost().getUrl();

                if(holder.itemView.getContext()!=null){
                    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(url).addListener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            holder.imageloadingbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).into(holder.postimage);
                }

                String description = list.get(position).getPost().getDescription();;
                if(!description.equals("")){
                    holder.descrition.setText(description);
                    holder.descrition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            if(list.get(position).getPost().getType().equals("video")){
                holder.videoplayerjz.widthRatio=1;
                holder.videoplayerjz.heightRatio=1;
                holder.videoplayerjz.fullscreenButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.videoplayerjz.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String url=list.get(position).getPost().getThumburl();

                holder.videoplayerjz.setUp(
                        list.get(position).getPost().getUrl(),
                        "", Jzvd.SCREEN_WINDOW_LIST);
                if(holder.itemView.getContext()!=null){
                    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(url).into(holder.videoplayerjz.thumbImageView);

                }

                String description = list.get(position).getPost().getDescription();
                if(!description.equals("")){
                    holder.descrition.setText(description);
                    holder.descrition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you load your image from Internet or local(res)? And may you show your adapter when you put to the image to imageview or other views then we can see if it is memory issue or others since you mentioned it lags

Comment: I have added my adapter code @CbL

Comment: @CbL Also i have to mention that app also sometimes crashes due to oom

Comment: I read the code you provided. I suggest you try to clear the imagelayout and videoplayerjz. As you try to request the image into that view when scrolling, some of the unseen imageview will be cache on the memory, this may cause the memory usage too heavy. You may try call Glide clear() in onViewRecycled see if this may improve the performance.

Comment: Glide recycle may ref http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html#listview-and-recyclerview